# What is the name of the process that runs userdata script on windows server EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Suppose a windows EC2 is launched with userdata (say a powershell script for instance). If you were to RDP into the instance and open task manager, what is the name of the userdata script task?

Answer (score 0):

- Windows 2016: `EC2Launch` [Configuring a Windows Instance Using EC2Launch - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2launch.html)
- Earlier: `EC2Config` [Configuring a Windows Instance Using the EC2Config Service - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2config-service.html)